# User de-selects Facebook permission while logging in with PFFacebookUtils

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pffacebookutils

I've been searching and trying to solve this issue with `PFFacebookUtils` and `Parse`, where the user logs in through Facebook but doesn't get saved in `Parse Data Browser`. Within this processes the user **de-selects a permission (eg. email)** and this results in an **empty User** in Parse Data Browser.

I have changed this processes and added some checks:

- Checking if permissions are given, if not then re-asks for
  permission.
- Everytime a new PFUser is created, so if permissions is
  not given, then the process starts over and I delete the old PFUser
  (so a new one is created).
- When all the permissions is in check and the data is ready to be
  saved to Parse it fails, and the user object shows up with
  no information in Parse.

Anyone experienced something similar to this? Empty PFUser data in Data Browser when logging in with Facebook?

Using `PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions`

Answer (score 0):

This could happen but you can prevent an user being created in your Parse User class by checking it on Cloud. In your User class `beforesave` trigger, you can easily detect if a user being signed up is a Facebook user or not by looking at `request.object.get("authData")`. Then you can use the access token (`request.object.get("authData").facebook.access_token`) to call the graph API and check if your user has granted all the permissions you require:

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions&access_token=xxx`

If not, you reject the user record by returning `response.error()`.